# Mounting second internal HDD in Sony Vaio

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, laptop, sony-vaio

I mounted new internal HDD instead of optical drive in Sony Vaio VPCEH laptop.
Special caddy was used for that purpose. Currently new HDD has power on it (i can see green light on caddy), but I can't see new disk in diskpart utility (`list disk`). And there is no pop-up window about new disk in disk management program. My OS in Windows 7, new drive in WD Blue 750Gb.

I updated SATA driver from manufacturer site, but nothing changed. Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Can you see the drive in the BIOS?

Comment: @jonno No, there is simplified h2o bios, all I can see about hdd is one line about the initial one.

Comment: Possibly a bad caddy or bad hard drive. Can you swap your primary hard drive with the one in the caddy and see if that's recognised in BIOS? And if so, try with your primary hard drive in the caddy. Should narrow it down.

Comment: As usual with this kind of problems first of all check if there is any update for your bios. If no then check if both hdd and caddy work on a different computer (check them seperately and then together).

Comment: @Jonno Thanks for your attention. I did an experiment - swapped drives as you mentioned. New HDD in not visible from bios (also double checked with Ubuntu USB drive), my primary HDD now placed in caddy and works just fine (as far as I can write this comment from my completely loaded Win7). So - is it a faulty new HDD or strange behavior of my BIOS that looks for old HDD wherever it placed? Should I remove the old one and try to load with only new one to check if it appears in BIOS?

Comment: Sounds like the hard drive is at fault then - your BIOS shouldn't be selectively ignoring it and I've not seen one do anything like that before. As @MustafaAKTAŞ stated, it may be worth checking for a BIOS update on your machine just in case, and if you can, test your new HDD in another machine. Can you tell if it even spins up? Hard drives can of course be DOA, however unlikely it is.

Comment: @Jonno Ok, i will tell a story that I can't believe myself. I removed old HDD, loaded with new one in default slot and it got recognized by BIOS. After that I added old HDD in optical slot and got my system working. Windows installed drivers for new one by itself, asked for reboot and now I got both HDDs working. Have no idea what happened. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Another tech oddity. Glad it's working :)